# System.AggregateException occurred with HDInsight emulator

Tags: c#, hadoop-streaming, azure-hdinsight

I am running a local HDInsight emulator in my windows machine and when I am trying to submit a MR job [C#] the following exception occurs.

```
System.AggregateException occurred
HResult=-2146233088
Message=One or more errors occurred.
Source=System.Core
StackTrace:
   at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryTaskGroupState.QueryEnd(Boolean userInitiatedDispose)
   at System.Linq.Parallel.MergeExecutor`1.Execute[TKey](PartitionedStream`2 partitions, Boolean ignoreOutput, ParallelMergeOptions options, TaskScheduler taskScheduler, Boolean isOrdered, CancellationState cancellationState, Int32 queryId)
   at System.Linq.Parallel.PartitionedStreamMerger`1.Receive[TKey](PartitionedStream`2 partitionedStream)
   at System.Linq.Parallel.ForAllOperator`1.WrapPartitionedStream[TKey](PartitionedStream`2 inputStream, IPartitionedStreamRecipient`1 recipient, Boolean preferStriping, QuerySettings settings)
   at System.Linq.Parallel.UnaryQueryOperator`2.UnaryQueryOperatorResults.ChildResultsRecipient.Receive[TKey](PartitionedStream`2 inputStream)
   at System.Linq.Parallel.UnaryQueryOperator`2.UnaryQueryOperatorResults.GivePartitionedStream(IPartitionedStreamRecipient`1 recipient)
   at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryOperator`1.GetOpenedEnumerator(Nullable`1 mergeOptions, Boolean suppressOrder, Boolean forEffect, QuerySettings querySettings)
   at System.Linq.Parallel.ForAllOperator`1.RunSynchronously()
   at Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce.Execution.Hadoop.LocalMapReduceStreamingExecutor.Execute(Boolean throwOnError)
   at Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce.Execution.Hadoop.StreamingJobExecutorBase.ExecuteCore(Type mapper, Type reducer, Type combiner, HadoopJobConfiguration config)
   at Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce.Execution.Hadoop.StreamingJobExecutorBase.Execute(Type mapperType, Type reducerType, Type combinerType, HadoopJobConfiguration config)
   at Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce.Execution.Hadoop.StreamingJobExecutorBase.Execute[TMapper,TReducer](HadoopJobConfiguration config)
   at hadoopTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\kalai\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\hadooptest\hadooptest\Program.cs:line 28
 InnerException: Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce.StreamingException
   HResult=-2146233088
   Message=Process failed (non-zero exit code). For hadoop job failure, see job-tracker portal for error information and logs. Cmd = C:\PROGRA~2\Syncfusion\BigData\12.2.0.1\Hadoop\bin\hadoop.cmd fs -copyFromLocal "C:\\Users\\kalai\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\hadooptest\\hadooptest\\bin\\Debug\\MRLib\\Microsoft.Hadoop.CombineDriver.exe" /user/kalai/dotnetcli/73cc83c8-9cb4-44e8-8eef-529cd95ec674/app/Microsoft.Hadoop.CombineDriver.exe. ExitCode=1
   Source=Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce
   StackTrace:
        at Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce.ProcessUtil.<Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce.Execution.Hadoop.IProcessUtil.RunAndThrowOnError>d__0.MoveNext()
   InnerException:
```

Any idea what could cause this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Its a valid exception. An `AggregateException` has a collection of exceptions in its `InnerExceptions` property that you can iterate over and inspect.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead i couldn't find any useful info from the inner exceptions to resolve this issue.